# Fancytooltips causes "Please fill out the following form" dialogue

Tags: viewers, fancytooltips

I observed this strange behaviour of fancytooltips: If more than 101 tooltips are defined, the Adobe Reader 11.0 or Adobe Acrobat 9.5.2/11.0.0 asks to "*Please fill out the following form. You can save data type into this form.*". With up to 101 tooltips everything is normal. This really puzzles me! Although it is not a big issue, I would prefer to get rid or hide this message before I send the document to someone else. Probably this is more an Adobe issue than a TeX problem, but maybe someone knows of a workaround.

[image]

**MWE**

```
% --- tooltip document
\begin{filecontents*}{fancytipmark.tex}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[createtips]{fancytooltips}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newcounter{x}
\setcounter{x}{1}
\begin{document}
\whiledo{\value{x}<102}% 101 works fine
{%
\keytip{\thex} \thex \stepcounter{x} \newpage%
}%
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

% --- main document
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[filename=fancytipmark, mouseover, movetips]{fancytooltips}
\begin{document}
abc
\end{document}
```

Comment: It has to be the problem with Adobe Reader. The problem doesn't show in `version 9.4.1`